# Unable to acess .env variables in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, backend

Both my index.ts file and .env file is stored in the src folder. but all my env variables are coming undefined .

Code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from "express";
import { dbconnection } from './DB/Connection.js';

import morgan from 'morgan';

import MainRouter from './Routes/MainRouter.js';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const App = express();

// Configure cookieParser middleware with a secret key
const secret = "a92i92ir0ji"; // Use your own secret key
App.use(cookieParser(secret));

App.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL); // Logging MONGODB_URL
});

App.use(express.json());
App.use("/api/v1", MainRouter);
App.use(morgan('dev'));

dbconnection()
  .then(() => {
    App.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL); // Logging MONGODB_URL
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('DATABASE NOT CONNECTED');
  });
```

will be grateful for any help

Comment: It depends on where you start your script from.
If you are in the root - then it won't catch .env under src folder.

Either take it to the root or start your script in context of src folder

Answer (score 0):

`dotenv.config()` accepts a path

`dotenv.config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/ca16eb5f09b9e5b2f2e7b068149c64480ab7ce77/lib/main.d.ts#L28

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you store your .env file in `src`, but you run your code from project root folder. Just move .env file to your project root folder (folder from where you are running your scripts etc.).
Also you can set path for `dotenv`:

```
config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })
```

But I will recomend you to separate env/config files and src

Comment: I did this but it still comes as undefined

Comment: this method worked while was doing it in javascript. but does not seem to work in typescript

Comment: Did you move your .env file to root or use path option?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node version v20.6.0+, you can use the [built-in .env](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.6.0) file support instead of using `dotenv` package

```bash
node --env-file=/custom/path/to/.env app.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import * as process from 'process'
```